# Using sessions to share data between different files and routes

Tags: node.js, express, session, dialogflow-es

Relatively new to node.js, I am wondering if anyone could help me please.

My MERN stack is working fine and authentication is working.

I am integrating Google's Dialogflow into a MERN stack and I would like to pass a user's username to the fulfillmentRoutes.js file.

The fulfillmentRoutes.js is as follows (I removed unnecessary code, it is just the bare bones);

**fulFillmentRoutes.js**

```
const {WebhookClient, Payload, Card} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const jwtDecode = require('jwt-decode');
const chatbot = require('../chatbot/chatbot');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const keys = require('../config/keys');
const Coupon = mongoose.model('coupon');
const Counter = mongoose.model('counters');
const Define = mongoose.model('define');
const sourceFile = require('./api/users.js');

const Themes = require('../models/Themes');
const Time = require('../models/Time');
const Questionexp = require('../models/Questionexp');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');


module.exports = app => {

app.post('/api/df_text_query', async (req, res) => {

let responses = await chatbot.textQuery(req.body.text, req.body.userID, req.body.parameters);
res.send(responses[0].queryResult);

});

app.post('/api/df_event_query', async (req, res) => {
let responses = await chatbot.eventQuery(req.body.event, req.body.userID, req.body.parameters);
res.send(responses[0].queryResult);


});



app.post('/', async (req, res) => {

const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res });

async function learn(agent) {

Demand.findOne({'course': agent.parameters.courses}, function(err, course) {
if (course !== null ) {
course.counter++;
course.save();
} else {
const demand = new Demand({course: agent.parameters.courses});
demand.save();
}
});
let responseText = `You want to learn about ${agent.parameters.courses}.
Here is a link to all of my courses: https://www.udemy.com/user/jana-bergant`;

let coupon = await Coupon.findOne({'course': agent.parameters.courses});
if (coupon !== null ) {
responseText = `You want to learn about ${agent.parameters.courses}.
Here is a link to the course: ${coupon.link}`;
}

agent.add(responseText);
}

async function welcome(agent) {

agent.add(“Hello!);

}


function fallback(agent) {
agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
}

let intentMap = new Map();


intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent - custom', continuesession);

agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});

}
```

The file above file sits in a folder outside the api folder, but inside the routes folder.

I want to share a user's username is personalise conversation using the fulfillment module above.

I have declared a session in my server.js file which sits in the main app root.

**server.js**

```
app.use(session({
         resave: true,
         saveUninitialized: true,
         secret: "secret"
        }));
```

In my users.js file in ./routes/api directory, I did the following in users.js

**users.js**

```
router.get('/current', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    req.session.test = req.user.email;
 res.send(req.session.test);
    res.json({
      id: req.user.id,
      firstname: req.user.firstname,
      lastname: req.user.lastname,
      email: req.user.email,
      week: req.user.week,
      age: req.user.age,
      time: req.user.time,
      bookmark: req.user.bookmark,
      alertDate: req.user.alertDate
    });
  }
);
```

However, when I use session extract line (below) in the fulfillmentRoutes.js (file quoted at the beginning) I get undefined.

```
username = req.session.test;`
```

Any help would be appreciated please.

Thank you,

P